# Using memcachier for session handling on Appfog

Tags: php, appfog, libmemcache

I have a PHP application hosted on Appfog.

I'm doing some load testing and running it across 3 instances, causing users to become logged out as the app currently uses the default $_SESSION variables to maintain a logged in state on a single instance.

I've added Appfog's memcachier service and can store variables in it, but how can I reconfigure PHP to use this to automatically store session data? All of the guides I have seen so far involve modifying php.ini, which is not accessible on Appfog.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit any of the php.ini variables in your .htaccess file.
https://docs.appfog.com/languages/php

Comment: But with what? Using memcache on Appfog requires declaring the path, username and password for your secure memcache server, but I can't see anyway to define these things via .htaccess